# access java script variables from other php files

Tags: javascript

I have threePHP files. Fist is `index.php` and second is `cal.php` and the third is `search.php`. In the `cal.php` i set two variables in javascript.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var startDate = "hi";
        var endDate = "there";
        console.log("Callback is being set!");
    });
</script>
```

I then include this `cal.php` and `search.php` file in my `index.php` file.

```
<div class="col-md-6 mt-20 pad-sm-0">
                <?php
                include("searchUI.php");
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mt-20 pad-sm-0 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                <?php
                include("calendarUI.php");
                ?> 
            </div>
```

On a button click in `index.php` i want to access the variables set in `cal.php` in the `search.php` file. I tried the following but i get UNDEFINED in the console.

```
function performSearch() {
        console.log(window.startDate);
        console.log(window.endDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`var` has function scope, so anything you define there can only be accessed inside that function.

You could declare without the `var` keyword and though it is a highly frowned upon practise it adds the variable into the global scope. (unless you run with `use strict;` which throws an error)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    startDate = "hi";  // creates global variable, not recommended
    endDate = "there";
    console.log("Callback is being set!");
});
```

A somewhat-decent approach* would be to just set the variables as keys to the window object similar to the way you tried accessing them.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.startDate = "hi";
    window.endDate = "there";
    console.log("Callback is being set!");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your script to this:

```
<script>
    var startDate, endDate;;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        startDate = "hi";
        endDate = "there";
        console.log("Callback is being set!");
    });
</script>
```

hope it works

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the var keyword which will make the variables global like below. Although having global variables is not a recommended approach as multiple global variables with same name can have undesired side effects.

Global variable are by-default tied to the global window object so you don't need to explicitly write window.startDate.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
     startDate = "hi";
     endDate = "there";
     console.log("Callback is being set!");
  });
</script>
```